# ( Blogger ) - Simple template - Sidebar spacing

Tags: padding, multiple-columns, blogger, margins, blogspot

I've been looking at this for hours and I can't figure it out. I've worked out the rest of the blog template, but this bit is not changing no matter what part of the code I change.

Basically, I want to get the spacing on the right hand side of the sidebar to match the spacing on the left hand side of the main content column (I think it was 35?).

As a secondary request, I would also like to see how it would look if I widened the gap between the columns (hopefully pushing the sidebar over to the right in doing so?).

I've tried posting this on the Blogger help forums as well, but there are some similar help requests that are a couple of years old and haven't had a reply..

I've changed just about everything labelled padding and/or margins, but nothing has made a difference to that section. I've tried changing the width of the columns, but still no luck. I managed to get the left column to move closer to the left side of the wrap, but changing something that I thought corresponded to the right made no difference at all.

The trial site (making changes here before I move it to my real blog) is http://testpagenotworking.blogspot.com .

There are a few other minor issues happening on the site, but nothing that doesn't fix itself up with the real images etc (header is the same size as the test header, so that shouldn't affect anything).

So I'd like it to look like:

|| -- | Column A |   | Column B | -- ||        rather than

|| -- | Column A | | Column B | ---- ||

I'm hoping this makes sense and that someone knows how to fix it! :)

Comment: Anyone? I'm really regretting using Blogger now. Half an hour setting up the template to suit my needs, three weeks trying to change one single section of padding code :\

Answer (score 0):

Okay, Blogger Templates are sometimes really hard to work with, so I suggest in General just writing it all yourself, if you are capable.

There is a class .section where you have an extra padding of 15px on each side, this could add to the right side of your content, which would end up in a result you showed.
Have you tried that yet?
Make sure you do inspect the element in your browser, there is hidden Blogger CSS which you sometimes have to overwrite in order to achieve the result you are looking for.